# Is the number (a) the root of the polynomial f (x)?

Tags: polynomials

$ a= \frac{2}{5}; f(x) = 10x^3 +6x^2 + x -2 $

Have difficulties with advanced polynomials of this type. I can not factor.To find the right root. Here is my solution:

$f(x) = 10x^3 +6x^2 + x -2 = 10x^3 +6x^2 +1x^2 -1x^2 +x -2 = (5x^2+x)(2x+1) -x^2 -2 $

I do not understand what I have to do.

Comment: Just substitute to check if $a$ makes the polynomial vanish. Then it is a root. Otherwise it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(\dfrac25)=\dfrac {80}{125}+\dfrac {24}{25}+\dfrac25-2=\dfrac{80}{125}+\dfrac{120}{125}+\dfrac{50}{125}-\dfrac{250}{125}=0$.  Thus it is a root.

Comment: Easier to show in practice than to explain xD

Answer (score 3):

If you want to show that $a$ is a root of $f$, just plug in $a=2/5$ for $x$ in the definition of $f$. That is to say, find $f(2/5)$.

If $f(2/5) = 0$, then $2/5$ is a root of $f$. Similarly, if it's not zero, then it's not a root.

If you want know how you can conclude that $2/5$ *might* be a root, the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) might be worth looking at. You still have to test the potential roots the theorem gives you, but it's better than trying to mess with that cubic right off the bat.

Comment: The theory without practice is nothing in the other as well as practice without theory. Thanks mr xD